# Frequent application not responding errors?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, performance, microsoft-office-2013, norton-antivirus

Recently I've begun to get a large number of application not responding errors, or very slow program load times.

I'm running Windows 7 Pro x64. Frequently the issue will be with Windows explorer, Office 2013, Chrome, or Norton Anti-Virus.

I've keep the resource monitor open to see what is happening when this occurs. I haven't been able to find anything consistent. I've change the NAV setting to reduce system load, run RKill to check for root kits and haven't found anything that helps.

I've noticed when Office has this problem that the disk response time for MSO.DLL is very high (~800ms). The disk is defragmented.

Any ideas of what I should try next?

Comment: Anything in the event viewer?

Comment: I just noticed that I'm having double digit hard faults/sec when things slow down. I have 8 GB of memory and only 33% in use when this was occurring. Why would I be having hard faults?